# Matlab JiT compiler optimizes away conditional code?

Tags: matlab

Say I have a class whose boolean property ifMsg determines whether the class methods will print diagnostic messages:

```
classdef myClass
   properties
      ifMsg=true
   end % properties
   methods
      function doSomething(o)
         disp('Hello world.')
         if o.ifMsg
            disp('I just greeted the world.')
         end % if o.ifMsg
      end % function doSomething
   end % methods
end % classdef
```

If I replaced `if o.ifMsg` with `if false && o.ifMsg`, would the Matlab JiT compiler optimize away the if-block?

**Background for the question**

My method implementation code is almost always in m-files that are separate from the classdef m-file.  If the JiT compiler doesn't optimize away if-blocks based on the constant conditional expression `o.ifMsg`, then when I need speed, I will be going through all my the m-files in their different class folders, and commenting out such if-blocks.  When I need the diagnostics, I will go through them all again to remove the comments.  Things are just a bit easier if I don't use separate method m-files, but I don't want the way that I organize my code to be dictated by this.

Comment: I modified the posting slightly for clarity, but I'm not sure what portion comes across as confusing.

Comment: I'm not really expecting, but asking if it does.  For compiled languages, optimization can be quite aggressive.  I'm wondering if I can rely on the JiT compiler to recognize a conditional expression that can in principle be evaluated at compile time, thus eliminating the actual test.  I have many of these conditional tests throughout my code.